# How to refresh authentication.idToken with GIDSignIn or GIDAuthentication?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-plus, amazon-cognito, google-signin

UPDATE 2015-10-28 - [Release 2.4.0 of Google Sign-In for iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release) appears to have resolved this problem, with both the idToken and the accessToken being refreshed as necessary by the new `GIDAuthentication` methods `getTokensWithHandler:` and `refreshTokensWithHandler:`. `GIDSignIn` method `SignInSilently` also refreshes both tokens.

---

I'm using AWS Mobile SDK for iOS, and I've implemented Google sign-in as a Cognito credentials provider using the [AWS Cognito Sync sample code](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoSync-Sample/Objective-C/CognitoSyncDemo) as a basis. The sign-in (and subsequent silent sign-in) flow is working correctly and signed-in users can access AWS resources like DynamoDB as intended.

My problem is that the `user.authentication.idToken` expires after one hour and at that point calls to AWS services fail with authentication errors. I can refresh the `user.authentication.accessToken` using

```
[self.googleUser.authentication refreshAccessTokenWithHandler:^(NSString *accessToken, NSError *error) {...}
```

but this doesn't update the `idToken`. I've also tried calling

```
[[GoogleSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
```

which gives me a valid idToken the first time it is called in the session, but although it completes successfully it doesn't refresh the idToken on subsequent calls within the same session.

I've been checking/dumping the token contents using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?id_token=<idToken>
```

and

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<accessToken>
```

I'm not sure whether the problem is that GIDSignIn is not updating idToken, or that AWS should be using the refreshToken somehow to auto-refresh the user at the backend. Either way I'm out of ideas.

Code snippets below. I've tested using GoogleSignIn 2.2.0 and 2.3.2 and experienced the same problem.

```
...
@interface MySignInClass <GIDSignInDelegate>
...
-(void) signInWithGoogle
{
    GIDSignIn *signIn = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.clientID = MY_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
    signIn.shouldFetchBasicProfile = YES;
    signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", @"openid", nil];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    if([signIn hasAuthInKeychain]) {
        [signIn signInSilently];
    } else {
        [signIn signIn];
    }
}
...
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn 
    didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
           withError:(NSError *)error 
{
    if (error != nil) {
        [self handleSignInError:error]; // Handle error
    }
    else {
        NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken;
        NSDictionary* logins = @{@"accounts.google.com": idToken};
        self.credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] 
           initWithRegionType:MY_COGNITO_REGION_TYPE
                   identityId:nil
               identityPoolId:MY_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL
                       logins:logins];
       AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] 
            initWithRegion:MY_COGNITO_REGION                                                              
       credentialsProvider:self.credentialsProvider];
       AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
       // AWSTask stuff removed for simplicity
       AWSTask* task = [self.credentialsProvider getIdentityId];
       ...
    }
}
...
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
     didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
                 withError:(NSError *)error 
{
    [self handleGoogleSignout]; // Do signout stuff
}
...
```

Comment: Linking over to [the discussion on AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=682133) in case there is progress from that side.

Comment: I just updated to Google Sign-In for iOS 2.4.0 and it appears to have been fixed. Both the idToken and the accessToken are now refreshed if they have expired and authentication is still valid. Here are the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/release). I will update the main post.

Answer (score 2):

Call the [GIDSignIn's signInSilently method](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/interface_g_i_d_sign_in.html#a61acc48595b637c8e89e7a05d21db7d2) like so:

```
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
```

This will end up calling your [`signIn:didSignInForUser:withError:`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api/protocol_g_i_d_sign_in_delegate-p.html#ae6b153cd3003767dfc13d4549a247c19) delegate method implementation with the idToken again.

I have verified that with the [2.4.0 release of Google Sign-In for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279485/how-to-refresh-authentication-idtoken-with-gidsignin-or-gidauthentication) the above approach of using signInSilently does indeed work for giving you a new idToken that isn't expired.

Comment: I receive the token in the call back when I tested. I guess you're saying when it's expired, it sends the same expired token. I'll see if I can find the patience to wait it out today and play with it. I have another idea if this doesn't work...

Comment: I'm talking about the idToken, not the access token. The signIn methods saves the token in the keychain, so signInSilently should do the same, but calling [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently].currentUser.authentication.idToken returns the same value.

Comment: Yep, I understood that and in my quick test, the IDToken is returned back to the delegate, but after waiting for an hour, I did see that it continues to return the old, now expired, token. I think the only way to make this happen is to hit Google's Token Endpoint again, but it isn't clear how to do that while using GIDSignIn since GIDSignIn doesn't seem to expose the original auth code.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Tried everything possible, that token is simply not being renewed by G+ iOS SDK.

The solution on our side was to send refresh_token to our server, and they were able to correctly renew the token on their side, by accessing one Google API, and then sending the new token back to my app. Unfortunately I don't have access now there, to tell you exactly which API, only tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Beny. Unfortunately in my case the backend is Amazon Cognito so I don't have any control over that either.

Comment: I really hope you will find the correct solution for this. Let us know if you succeed.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a timer at 30 mins., then calling the signInSilently?

Comment: It was a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: I just found out myself. Thanks for responding and sorry for the outdated post.